# Build curl lib with Mingw compiler

Tags: c++, windows, curl, mingw

I want to use the curl lib in my project (c++ QT creator on windows), I download the zip lib file from the website https://curl.se/download.html (Version 7.82.0)
and I wanted to build it using the **Makefile** with this commend
`mingw32-make mingw32` as described in the documentation https://curl.se/docs/install.html

but unfortunately, I am getting an error

```
mingw32-make mingw32
[....]
gcc   -s -m32 -static -o curl.exe curl.res slist_wc.o tool_binmode.o tool_bname.o 
tool_cb_dbg.o tool_cb_hdr.o tool_cb_prg.o tool_cb_rea.o tool_cb_see.o tool_cb_wrt.o 
tool_cfgable.o tool_dirhie.o tool_doswin.o tool_easysrc.o tool_filetime.o tool_findfile.o 
tool_formparse.o tool_getparam.o tool_getpass.o tool_help.o tool_helpers.o tool_hugehelp.o 
tool_libinfo.o tool_listhelp.o tool_main.o tool_msgs.o tool_operate.o tool_operhlp.o 
tool_panykey.o tool_paramhlp.o tool_parsecfg.o tool_progress.o tool_strdup.o tool_setopt.o 
tool_sleep.o tool_urlglob.o tool_util.o tool_vms.o tool_writeout.o tool_writeout_json.o 
tool_xattr.o strtoofft.o nonblock.o warnless.o curl_ctype.o curl_multibyte.o version_win32.o 
dynbuf.o -L../lib -lcurl -lwldap32 -lws2_32
../lib\libcurl.a: error adding symbols: Archive has no index; run ranlib to add one
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [curl.exe] Fehler 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `D:/Dev/API/curl-7.82.0/src'
make: *** [mingw32] Fehler 2
```

I tried to run `ranlib lib\libcurl.a` but the issue is still there,

does anyone have an idea about it?

One more question: is it possible also to build it with mingw64?

Comment: did you execute it in /curl-7.82.0/src or just in /curl-7.82.0?

Comment: @korzck yes it's compiling both- Here is in the Make file in the root folder 
mingw32:
 $(MAKE) -C lib -f Makefile.m32
 $(MAKE) -C src -f Makefile.m32